# Reactjs redirect from within function

Tags: reactjs

I have a header/navbar function component with a logout button. When the user successfully logs out, I would like them to be redirected to the login route.

Using `react-router-dom` I have tried importing and using `Redirect`, `History`, `withRouter` and `props.history.push` but none of them seem to redirect.

All the answers and tutorials I have seen use a class component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, NavLink, useHistory, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";


function NavBar(props) {

  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  async function onLoad() {
    try {
      await Auth.currentSession();
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e !== "No current user") {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
    setIsAuthenticating(false);
  }

  async function signOut() {
    console.log("Signing out.");
    await Auth.signOut();
    userHasAuthenticated(false);
    props.history.push("/login"); //  Cannot get redirect to work
    console.log("Signed out.");
  }

return (
...
<Nav className='d-md-down-none' navbar>
...
<UncontrolledDropdown>
 <DropdownMenu right>
...
  <DropdownItem onClick={signOut}>
              <i className='fa fa-lock'></i> Logout
  </DropdownItem>
 </DropdownMenu>
</UncontrolledDropdown>
</Nav>
);
}
export default NavBar;
```

When the Logout button is clicked the Cognito auth session data is all wiped correctly, both "Signing out" and "Signed out" appear in the browser console, but the user is not redirected, and there are no errors or warnings in the console.

NavBar is a child component of a higher level Layout component.

Comment: what do you use for Router?

Comment: In my App.js I have `<BrowserRouter>` with a `<Switch>` the `DropdownItem>`'s are in `NavItem` then `NavLink` elements. ohhh I see what you mean, I copy/pasted the wrong imports.. updated the post.

Comment: `onClick={signOut()}` this will invoke the `signOut` method on each render instead of on click. Try `onClick={signOut}`. Also react router has a `Redirect` component which when rendered causes a redirect

Comment: I updated the onClick to just `signOut` but still get the same result. I also tried adding `<Redirect to='/login' />` to the function, but it throws an error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Answer (score 0):

Please create a file "useRouter.js"

```
import {useContext} from 'react'
import {__RouterContext} from 'react-router'

export default () => useContext(__RouterContext);
```

and insert the following

```
import useRouter from 'path to useRouter.js'

...

function SignUpForm(props: any) {
...
const router = useRouter()

...
router.history.push('/signin'); // write this where you want to push
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggested, but it still does not redirect.